# Generating Instant Web Renderings

Tags: javascript, html, flash, web, 3d

This might seem like an obvious question, but I'm not a developer and I am looking for some guidance. I would like to build a web application that allows users to upload a vector file that's a canvas for a 3D model. The canvas would then be applied to the 3D model in the "background" using what I presume would be some sort of script, and the resulting rendering would be made available for download almost instantly. What sort of programming language would I use for this? What tools exist to develop such an application? The 3D model is not a regular geometric object.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What is meant by a "canvas" for a 3D model? a texture?

Comment: No textures. Just a simple skin applied to an irregular-shaped object.

Comment: So the 3D model does not include "skin" ( = polygons? triangles?); what does the model include, and what does the uploaded skin include?

Comment: Sorry, let me put this in terms commonly used in 3ds max. So, the user would upload a texture overlaid on a predefined UVMap of the 3D object. The texture would then be applied to the 3D object according to the UVMap coordinates.

Comment: Where does the 3D model come from - does the user upload it? or is it part of the web application?

Comment: It would be a part of the web application—ideally done on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to do the rendering on the client side (i.e. in the browser). In that case, you would use Javascript as the programming language, and a library like Three.js to associate the skin with the 3D model and render the result. In this scenario, the user would not upload the texture but keep it on the client; but the browser would (transparently, without the user having to do anything) download the 3D model to the browser (assuming the model comes from the server, not from the user). There would be minimal programming on the server side.
The 3D rendering can be done very fast in the browser these days, especially when using WebGL, as Three.js can.

I'm not sure whether you really mean it's a requirement that the user be able to *download* the rendered image (save it to a file), as opposed to taking a screenshot and saving that to a file.

If you wanted to do the rendering on the server side, I suppose you could use something like [POV-Ray](http://povray.org), since it has a command-line interface. In this scenario, the user would upload the skin, POV-Ray would render the input files into an output image, and the user would download the image.

More specifics would depend on the format of the skin and of the 3D model.

Comment: Thanks very much, LarsH. This provides me with a good starting point. I'm not well versed with file formats, but I'm guessing that I'll have to use free/open file formats? For example, if I wanted the user to upload an adobe vector file (.ai) skin, then I would have to convert it to an image file somehow before it could be used by the 3D model? What free/open file formats could be used to build the 3D model? Would I even be able to accept a user uploaded .ai file to convert to an image without the proper licensing and software from adobe. Sorry, this is all new to me.

Comment: Sorry @user2035965, I'm not familiar with Adobe vector format (.ai). You might want to post a separate question about that. My experience has been that this site is not as strong on answering graphics questions as it is on other topics, so if you don't get answers here, try another site. This article about COLLADA has some good info about it and other 3D formats: http://libregraphicsworld.org/blog/entry/collada-becomes-iso-standard

Comment: Much appreciated, LarsH!